# how visualize multi channel of feature from PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, visualize

I'm almost newbie at PyTorch

One of my output size from conv is [1, 25, 8, 32]
(25=channel, 8=height, 32=width)

I can use squeeze and make it to [25, 8, 32].

But I'm confused with 25 channel.

When I want to visualize sum of 25 channel and make to one GRAYorRGB image(1or3x8x32),How can i deal with in code??

I can use matplot or tensorboardX for visualizing..

Comment: I think you usually just visualize the channels separately like [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Deep-features-visualization-a-output-feature-maps-and-b-convolution-kernels-of-the_fig3_320461081)

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to visualize images with more than 3 channels and it is unclear what a feature vector in 25 dimensional space actually looks like.

The most straight forward approach would be to visualize the 8x32 feature maps you have as *separate* 25 gray scale images of size 8x32. Each image will show how how "sensitive" is a specific neuron/conv filter/channel (these are all equivalent) to the input at a certain spatial location.

There are more intricate methods for feature visualization, you can find more details about them in [this blog post](https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/).